# nightwatch.js - how to prevent browser to open for api tests

Tags: node.js, nightwatch.js

I am looking for best javascript framework that can be used for both UI and api tests. I am wondering if nightwatch.js can be good for it. 
Works great with browser, but can't prevent browser to open for api tests

Comment: I don't understand your question, what does "but can't prevent browser to open for api tests" mean?

Comment: For api tests... i dont want my browser to popup

Comment: -1 - Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid calling any `browser` commands of nightwatch and just use the test structure of nightwatchjs to trigger api calls and assert them with good old node assert but personally I would keep them separate.

UI tests take time and are brittle where API tests take a fraction of the time and require less maintenance.
Nightwatchjs is designed as UI test framework and although you could possibly hack it to do what you want, you will end up spending more resources to do so.